# Change the color of Cells in sheet2 based on values in sheet 1

Tags: arrays, colors, background

I need to update the Work product status in Sheets 2 based on a values in 2 columns in a sheet1

In Sheet1 I have navigate through Column L and M and update the Workproduct status in Sheet2,
Column M in Sheet1 has Dropdown menu = NOK, OK, In Progress, NA and Column L can have either String "Q" or not.

Work product status in Sheet2 = Red , if any of the cell in Column L has the Value Q and corresponding cell in Column M has the value equal to NOK.

Work product status in Sheet2 = Green , if all cells in Column M has the value equal to "OK"
Work product status in Sheet2 = Yellow, If any of the Cells in Column M has value equal to "In Progress" and
"NOTOK"
If all the cells in Column M in Sheet1 has the value to NA ,then it should not update any color in sheet2

Case 1
Sheet1

| Column L | Column M |
| --- | --- |
| Q | NOTOK |
| Q | Inprogres |
|  | OK |
|  | NA |

Sheet 2

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Wp1 | Red |

Case 2
Sheet 1
| Column L | Column M |
| -------- | -------- |
| Q        | OK       |
| Q        | OK       |
|          | NOTOK    |
|          | NOTOK    |

Sheet 2

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Wp1 | No update |

For i = 8 To 20
' If arrData(i, 1) = KEY_COLQ Then
Set Cell2 = Range("M8:M19").Find("NOK - Work not completed.", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
If Not Cell2 Is Nothing Then
ThiswWorkbook.Worksheets("Workproduct_status").Range("C2").Interior.Color = vbRed
Else
ThiswWorkbook.Worksheets("Workproduct_status").Range("C2").Interior.Color = xlNone
End If

```
       Next i
```